# Custom list adapter for ListView or ListFragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, listadapter

How can we define Custom ListAdapter(like ArrayAdapter or IconicAdapter) for ListView in activity? How can we do the same for ListFragments? any example or links will be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ListFragment` holds a `ListView`, so there is really no difference. You just call `getListView()` to get a reference and then you can set an adapter as usual.

Comment: Don't see what has changed... It is exactly the same. Any examples you have for `ListView` custom adapters, you can use in a `ListFragment'.

Answer (score 0):

In my ListFragment onActivityCreated I set the adapter and notify.

The adapter is custom, which inflates a customview. The contents of the text view never show up.

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
    String[] items;


    public MyAdapter(String[] url) {
        items = url;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                    R.layout.itemwithimage, null);
        }

        TextView txt = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listtextView);
        txt.setText(items[position]);
        Log.d(TAG, "string " + items[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        if (items == null)
            return 0;

        return items.length;
    }
}
```